# Maintaining NuGet libraries version in various projects with shared output

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, bin

I keep two projects in each location:

> Project A (C: \ GitRepository \ xxx \ yyy \ zzz \ ProjectA.sln
>
> Project A packages (C: \ GitRepository \ xxx \ yyy \ zzz \ packages
>
> Project B (C: \ GitRepository \ xxx \ yyy \ sss \ ProjectB.sln
>
> Project B packages (C: \ GitRepository \ xxx \ yyy \ sss \ packages
>
> Both projects have a common output (C: \ GitRepository \ xxx \ bin) - this is obligatory

When one team create project and add NuGet package to project (new package is downloaded by default). Then add this project to SolutionA. We get situation where AutoMapper in rev. eg. 20 in SolutionA and other rev. eg. 19 in SolutionB.

When compiling projects Jenkins MSBuild Build Project A gets the missing package rev. 20, Project B already has a package 19, but it needs newer version 20 . Error comes  when read the correct version of the library.

Solutions:

1. One solution is to remove attributes from references specified version but you want to keep your shared libraries.
2. The team came up with a solution to make one such project. NuGetRepository and only through this project to add the library to the output. Other projects must host libraries builded from NuGetRepository.csproj have access through files, not project reference. We would like to keep one version in each project without conflicts.

Is solution 2 good?